# calculate the text that can be contained in a container with a particular size

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring, contentsize

I'm searching for a way to get the range of NSAttributedString that can be contained inside containers with a particular size.

Some more details :

The text is dynamic, i'm getting it with api calls.
The layout is very similar to layouts used inside flipboard application : I have the dynamic number of pages, some of pages have an image on top with a dynamic height, the remaining space have to be filled with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine a bounds (size) of text using UIKit additions to NSString: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html

So you can start with small amount of text and incrementally increase it until you reach required size.

Comment: can you give me some more details please ?

Comment: If you know a size of empty space to be "filled" with text then you can use `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` to determine how much space the actual string will take. Then if required space is less then available - append another portion of text to string and repeat measurements.

Actually I'm not sure is this approach suitable for NSAttributedString, but it can be used with NSString.